# How to test if else conditions in jest node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have written one function in which there is one if else condition. I want to test that if else condition.
So my function is below

```
function dateFunction(date){
today = new Date() // it is taking todays date.
dateToBeChecked = date // date received in function parameter 
 
if (dateToBeChecked < today){
return false
}
else {
   return true
  }
}
```

So I want to write test cases for if else condition. Can anyone please help me on that.

Comment: in your test provide `date` greater than `today`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can test boolean value using toBeTruthy() and toBeFalsy() method.

```
test('Expect true from return value of dateFunction', () => {
  expect(dateFunction(new Date("05/24/2021"))).toBeTruthy();
  expect(dateFunction(new Date("05/24/2021"))).not.toBeFalsy();
});
```

Comment: you only test one case

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to dates it's best to inject the current date as a function parameter and to give it a default value. This way you have the guarantee that your tests won't fail in the future.

```js
function dateFunction(date, today = new Date) {
   if (dateToBeChecked < today) {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}

test('return false if it\'s a past date', () => {
  expect(dateFunction(0, 1)).toBe(false)
})

test('return true if it\'s a future date', () => {
  expect(dateFunction(1, 0)).toBe(true)
})
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `else if` in this way.

```
if (true) {
  // My code here
} else if (false){
  // My code heee
} else {
  // My code here
}
```